# Making global variable loop freeze/stop inside a function for a while

Tags: python, loops, scope, global-variables, local-variables

I have the function `fun()` having a global variable x ranging(0,11). I need the value of the global variable x to stop/freeze when the function enters the `copying()` function. here is my code.

```
import os
from std_msgs.msg import String
from datetime import datetime

def fun():
    while True:
        global x
        for x in range(12):
            cmd=f'rosbag record -O /home/mubashir/catkin_ws/src/germany1_trush/rosbag/{x}.bag /web_cam --duration 5 '
            os.system(cmd)

def callback(data):
    print(data.data)
    if data.data == "True":
        pub.publish(f"{datetime.now()}")
        print("Callback function ")
        copying()

def copying():
    print(x)
    print("I want x not increasing here ")

def listener():
     rospy.Subscriber("button_press", String, callback)
     rospy.spin()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fun()
    listener()
```

Comment: Than don't change it? I don't understand the issue.

Comment: when the program enters in `copying()` function at that time what is the value of x I only what that. not incrementing the value of x. just want to freeze the value of x when the function enter copy function.

Comment: You can't "freeze" the value. Just don't change it. If you want to work with this value you can create a local variable with the same value.

Comment: Actually, the `copying()` function copies the file recorded by cmd in `fun()`. The file duration is 10 sec. and I want the past, present, and future files to be saved. Therefore I want to freeze the vale of x when program is inside `copying()` function.  How can I do it any idea?

Comment: You cannot deny another part of the software to change a global variable. If you want that, you need to use a locking mechanism. However, I guess your ansatz is not correct, could you explain what you actually want to achieve with your code?